# Is it possible to reverse the Pearsonr?

Tags: statistics, correlation

Given a Pearson correlation coefficient (PCC) and a list of values (target), can I generate another list of values with roughly the same PCC as the targeting list?

For example, given a list of values x = [1,2,3,4,5] and a PCC=0.8. I want to generate another list y = [a,b,c,d,e], so that x and y will have a PCC around 0.8.

Comment: You may consider the geometric interpretation to constructive such cases. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Geometric_interpretation